# Is the input embedding split along the embedding dimension so that every head of the multi-head-attention module just gets a part of the input data?

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, attention, word-embedding, embeddings

So I found two contradictory explanations of the MHA (multi-head-self-attention-module):

In **the first approach**, the input embedding (= the input matrix) is split along the embedding dimension and all heads are given a subset of the dimensions/features of each word.
Some websites supporting this theory:
https://medium.com/@smitasasindran/12-attention-mechanisms-multihead-attention-958041a35553

-> Quote: "The input has been split into multiple heads, and we are running the attention model separately on each of these heads."

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-code-the-transformer-in-pytorch-24db27c8f9ec#3fa3 
-> Quote: "In multi-head attention we split the embedding vector into N heads, so they will then have the dimensions batch_size * N * seq_len * (d_model / N)."

**The second approach** assumes that all heads receive the entire input data, but different weight matrices are used for each head depending on the number of heads.
This theory is well explained on https://hungsblog.de/en/technology/learnings/visual-explanation-of-multi-head-attention/

-> Quote: "Each head is responsible to fully calculate the attention for the whole embedding, not just for a subset of it and creates h attention matrices"

I tend to the second explanation, but have not been able to find a satisfactory and contradiction-free answer so far.